# Angular 5, input formatting and parsing, what is a standard solution

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an input field and want to enter a float number using a German locale. My solution is following, it is working, but it is complicated and there should be a better approach?

```
<input matInput [ngModel]="amount | number: '0.2-2'" 
(blur)="transformAmount($event)" (keyup.enter)="transformAmount($event)"/>

transformAmount(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
  this.amount = parseFloat(event.target.value.replace('.', '').replace(',','.'));
  console.log('amount=' + this.amount);
}
```

Comment: The is also a question how to parse a number in a more generic way using a locale. replace('.', '').replace(',','.') is working with German but it is not generic

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with the formatting reactive form input field. To solve it I have used this [article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-material-matinput-control-with-thousands-separation-ebcbb7b027f4). I have created a slightly modified version to fit my needs.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, HostListener, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/material';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { formatNumber } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[localizedNumericInput]',
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: LocalizedNumericInputDirective },
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => LocalizedNumericInputDirective),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class LocalizedNumericInputDirective implements ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy {
  locale = 'en';
  decimalMarker: string;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) {
  }

  private _value: string | null;

  get value(): string | null {
    return this._value;
  }

  @Input('value')
  set value(value: string | null) {
    this._value = value;
    this.formatValue(value);
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
  input(value) {
    //Find all numerics, decimal marker(, or .) and -
    //It will delete thousandSeparator cos it's always opposite to decimal marker
    const regExp = new RegExp(`[^\\d${this.decimalMarker}-]`, 'g');
    //Separate value on before and after decimal marker
    const [integer, decimal] = value.replace(regExp, '').split(this.decimalMarker);

    //Send non localized value, with dot as decimalMarker to API
    this._value = decimal ? integer.concat('.', decimal) : integer;

    // If decimal separator is last character don't update
    // because it will delete . || ,
    if (this.isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value)) {
      this._value = value;
    }

    // here to notify Angular Validators
    this._onChange(this._value);
  }

  @HostListener('blur')
  _onBlur() {
    /**
     * Adding thousand separators
     */
    this.formatValue(this._value);
  }

  @HostListener('focus')
  onFocus() {
    this.unFormatValue();
  }

  _onChange(value: any): void {}

  /**
   * @param value
   * apply formatting on value assignment
   */
  writeValue(value: any) {
    this._value = value;
    this.formatValue(this._value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
    this._onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}

  isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value: any) {
    return isNaN(value[value.length - 1]);
  }


  private formatValue(value: string | null) {
    if (value === null) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = '';
      return;
    }

    if (this.isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value)) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = value;
      return;
    }

    // Conclude the decimal and thousand separators from locale
    const [thousandSeparator, decimalMarker] = formatNumber(1000.99, this.locale).replace(/\d/g, '');
    this.decimalMarker = decimalMarker;

    //Here value should always come with . as decimal marker thus any other behavior is bug
    const [integer, decimal] = value.split('.');

    //Group every three elements, and add thousandSeparator after them
    this.element.nativeElement.value = integer.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousandSeparator);

    //Add decimals and decimalMarker if any
    if (decimal) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = this.element.nativeElement.value.concat(decimalMarker, decimal);
    }
  }

  private unFormatValue() {
    const value = this.element.nativeElement.value;
    if (this.isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value)) {
      return;
    }
    const regExp = new RegExp(`[^\\d${this.decimalMarker}-]`, 'g');
    const [integer, decimal] = value.replace(regExp, '').split(this.decimalMarker);

    this._value = integer.concat('.', decimal);
    if (value) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = this._value;
    } else {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = '';
    }
  }
}
```

To use this directive your html should look like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>Value</mat-label>
<input
        type="text"
        localizedNumericInput
        matInput
        autocomplete="off"
        formControlName="value"
      />
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is fine.

There is no better way to transform data from variable to `input` than `Pipe` and there is no better way to transform data from `input` to variable than a function bound to DOM events.

In order to simplify your code a bit you could do the following:

```
<input matInput [ngModel]="amount | number: '0.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="transformAmount($event)"/>

transformAmount(event) {
  console.log(event);
  this.amount = parseFloat(event.replace('.', '').replace(',','.'));
  console.log('amount=' + this.amount);
}
```

Comment: ngModelChange occurs every time I change something, for example I type 1 and get 1,00 immediately, disturbing me typing, also if type 1000 I get 1.000.

Comment: Ok then it might not suit your needs. What you already did looks fine to me

Answer (score 3):

Yes this part is a little bit tricky. Futhermore sometime you need to display something that is not really the actual value.

The actual best solution I have found it to create a custom component (working with ngModel, see about ControlValueAccessor) for my input and this one look like this base on what you are trying to do.

html :

```
<input [formControl]="inputFormControl" #myInput />
```

ts :

```
@ViewChild('myInput') inputElm: ElementRef;
formGroup: FormGroup;
value: number;

this.inputFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
  if (value) {
    const displayValue = ('' + value).replace(',', '.');
    this.value = parseFloat(displayValue); // manage the value
    this.inputFormControl.setValue(this.value, { emitEvent: false });
    this.inputElm.nativeElement.value = new DecimalPipe(this.localId).transform(displayValue, '0.2-2'); //control the display
  }
});
```

In some way you will certainly find it a bit more complicated but at the end it give you also more control ;)

Comment: it happens the same, you type 1 and get 1,00 immediately, the cursor occurs at the very end

Comment: Yes my code is not completely optimise for your example. It was just for showing you an another way of doing what you are trying to do. I think the format change should only occurred onBlur in your case  like your writes. But in some situation like valid against a regex it can be usefull

Answer (score 0):

I created a Directive using an information from this [Angular 2 Directives to Format Text as you Type](https://medium.com/@firecube/angular-2-directives-to-format-text-as-you-type-e2c8e3ca09d8) article.

It is working but i don't unterstand why 'Change' suffix is necessary and why i can't separate an event from an input doing line this: (appNumberInput)=.... [appNumberInput]=....

```
<input [(appNumberInput)]="amount" format="0.2-2" />
```

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appNumberInput]',

})
export class NumberInputDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    appNumberInput: any;

    @Input()
    format: string;

    @HostBinding('value')
    stringValue: string;


    @Output() appNumberInputChange: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.stringValue = this.decimalPipe.transform(this.appNumberInput, this.format);
    }

    @HostListener('blue', ['$event.target.value'])
    @HostListener('keyup.enter', ['$event.target.value'])
    formatANumber(value) {
        const numberValue = parseFloat(value.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
        this.stringValue = this.decimalPipe.transform(numberValue, this.format);
        this.appNumberInputChange.next(numberValue);

  }
}
```

Comment: This is going in a great direction, but there are a number issues with this solution.  A simple one is `@HostListener('blue', ['$event.target.value'])` should read `@HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])` (blur not blue).  Also, I don't think that EventEmitter is providing any value. Also the `appNumberInput` Input doesn't provide much value.  I'm pretty sure `this.stringValue = ` is all you need.

Comment: `[appNumberInput]` and `(appNumberInputChange)` can be concatenated with the `[(appNumberInput)]` syntax. The `Change` suffix is needed to distinguish the input from the output, since they share the same namespace in JavaScript